# как правильно создать в идеи JavaEE проект на maven в котором будет два проекта EJB и JSF(.WAR)

Tags: java-ee, maven, jsf, ejb

Мне достался проект в интересной связке. Это проект в  Netbeans в котором есть проект JavaEE(EJB+JSF) это два под проекта. Тоесть я открываю проект и вижу основной проект в котором ничего нет, только два подпроекта.  EJB  и  WAR(JSF). Сборка осуществляется на  ANT. А сервер на котором крутиться GlassFis 4.1

Я хочу все это переделать на Intellij IDEA + maven  сервер оставить GlassFis 4.1 но при попытке создать проект в идеи, я вижу только  ANT шаблоны.

Вопрос, как правильно создать в идеи JavaEE проект на  maven  в котором будет два проекта  EJB  и  JSF(.WAR)

Answer (score 1):

```
create new project -> maven и все
```

потом напишешь GroupID, и ArtifactId
потом создаешь 2 модуля

Comment: так и сделал. Модуль для  EJB обычный а вот для  WAR нужно чтобы он был веб проектом.  B  и я сделал это, но теперь не могу собрать проект

Comment: если хочешь что бы какой то модуль был WAR а какойто Jar то просто в мавене pom.xml пропиши <packaging>war</packaging> или <packaging>jar</packaging> потом через мавен собери

Answer (score 0):

Установи NetBeans (с плагином Maven), он тебе автоматически создаст проекты.